# Django + Vite + Vue with Router does not work

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I am trying to run the basic Vite default app with router to run a vue 3 front end along with Django. However I am receiving the following error which generally doesn't come when running only a Vite with vue router app.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at index-2331cb67.js:5:33627)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at AboutView-d0a85a00.js:1:1)
```

I have updated [the code here](https://github.com/Jayesh-Mahato/djangovitevue). Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be resolved in following 2 ways:

1. Using type="module" in Django template dynamic script calling section.
2. Changing store.js to declare store and then export it as default.
3. Using any dynamic imports via [defineAsyncComponent()](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#async-components)

[Working code is updated here.](https://github.com/Jayesh-Mahato/djangovitevue)